# Input Field Onchange not allowing to type

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple Input field which gets a value from onComponentMount. Now I want the user to be able to change value but Its not working. Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const IPAddress = await publicIp.v4();
    this.setState({ Client_IP: IPAddress })
  }

  eventHandler = () => (e: any) => {
    e.persist()
    this.setState((prevState: any) => ({
      IPObject: {
        ...prevState.IPObject,
        IPList: e?.target?.value
      }
    }));
  }

    <Input placeholder="IP address" required={true}
      value={this.state.Client_IP} onChange={this.eventHandler()}></Input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input onChange to:

```
onChange={this.eventHandler}
```

When you use parantheses, you have to call it like an arrow function:

```
onChange={() => this.eventHandler()}
```

And make sure you change the field you want, in that `eventHandler`

Comment: Just to explain why this is the case: A parameter containing `this.eventHandler` passes in the function itself, and `this.eventHandler()` runs the function and then passes in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is constantly calling `eventHandler` function.

See here [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for eventHandling with JSX in react

The correct syntax will be

```
  <Input placeholder="IP address" required={true} value={this.state.Client_IP} onChange={() => this.eventHandler()}></Input>
```

Or

```
  <Input placeholder="IP address" required={true} value={this.state.Client_IP} onChange={this.eventHandler}></Input>
```